Не получается добавить персонажа в игру Unreal Engine 5.3
У меня есть проект, в котором используются анимации SuperheroFlightAnimations, я хотел добавить своего персонажа, сделать реалтайм ретаргет. Использовал в качестве создания скелета для Mesh - ActorCore accurig. Но в этом проекте нет папки mannyquins_ue4, которая нужна для ретаргета RTG и IK скелета. Хотел попробовать добавить эту папку из другого проекта, но после ретаргета получается это:

в общем любой меш, который изначально должен находится в правильной позе и положении (проверял в других проектах, там все нормально) находится сверху, и это не вся проблема, даже если поставить его в правильное положение, он не реагирует ни на какие анимации, то есть если действовать как показано в видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSUx6MANqBw&t=891s
то ничего не работает (в видео показывается как сделать реалтайм ретаргет)
также я пробовал сделать ретаргет в другом проекте с superheroflightassets и перекинуть все файлы ik, rtg, animation blueprint и самого персонажа в действующий проект, но ситуация та же, что и на скриншоте.
Как решить эту проблему? Можете подсказать что не так или дать инструкцию еще какого-либо способа сделать ретаргет всех анимаций и перенести на другого персонажа.
Репозиторий проекта, в котором не получается заменить персонажа: https://github.com/ProdiG66/ManOfSteel
